# Is Tamura the original Homura?

Tags: madoka-magica

The Puella Magi Homura Tamura spinoff manga follows Tamura, who is actually Homura, but no one can ever remember her name and she gets called Tamura (among other things) until it sticks.

During the series, we find out that there's a bar called Akemi-ya where different versions of Homura congregate in between repetitions of the timeline, relax, eat, drink, compare experiences, and do short skits.

[image: akemi-ya explained]

Some of the Homuras are radically different from the original Homura in the anime. There's a prankster Homura, a child genius Homura, and a princess Homura served by a butler Homura, like an all-Homura version of Mayo Chiki.

While reading Volume 1, I assumed Tamura, the main Homura, was supposed to be the original Homura from the anime, as in the other spinoff manga. But unlike the original Homura, Tamura is able to reflect on her own actions, recognize mistakes, and feel empathy (sometimes excessively). We see in Volume 1 that there are lookalike timeflows that correspond closely to the original, non-silly timeline, so Tamura could actually be a Homura from a lookalike timeline. What evidence is there in the series for or against Tamura being the original Homura from the anime?

Comment: One could assume that the timelines we saw in the anime isn't all the timelines Homura went to as if i recall correctly the Oriko manga is only of the timelines Homura terminated. also Homura hasn't a;ways been so stoic, remember how excited she was after becoming a Puella Magi, turning back time and seeing Madoka in class. it's possible that before the timeline Mami went crazy and tried to kill everyone there was other timelines that the anime didn't show

Comment: @Memor-X Yeah, as far as I know there were supposed to be many, many timelines as Homura spent around 12 years traveling in time, so it's definitely possible that Tamura is the original Homura in an earlier time. On the other hand, in the Tech Support chapter from Volume 1, Tamura admits to the support tech that she's "really" 26 years old, which would put her towards the end of her travels and closer to the time period of the anime, so I'd expect her to be more dour by this point. Tamura also has already stopped wearing glasses. That all made me think she might not be our Homura.

Answer (score 1):

Well, after the volumen 1 and 2, we can assume isn't Homura, because in one of the timeflows she find the one of the Mami's who was crazy and try to shot Madoka.
Beside, Tamura look like she have more empathy than Homura (just remember the dog and her new shield or her encourt with Mami)
But we can't assume nothing until they show us the original timeflow of Tamura

Comment: I don't remember when she met the crazed Mami, can you remind me which volume and chapter? And I mentioned in the question that Tamura seems to have more empathy than Homura, but I don't consider that sufficient evidence since the original Homura changed a lot more from when she started to the time of the series than the differences between Tamura and the original Homura.